# What is magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, history

http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/em/el2.pdf

I'm reading the article above and have a question in  "3.5.1 A History of Magnetostatics". I wonder what magnetic field is. So I started reading 3.5.1 and don't understand  how Jean-Baptiste Biot and F´elix Savart determined the strength of the magnetic field. Explanation above it just shows experimental phenomenon. Where does the 'strength' of magnetic field come from??
Please don't just say maxwell's equation or lorentz force. I want to know about historical flow.

Comment: So you're not asking what a magnetic field is, you're asking what people thought it might have been in the past?

Comment: I want to know what people thought in the past and how it was formulated in its modern form.

Comment: It would help if you said what you understand about electric fields. Magnetic fields aren’t that different.